# ¿Como colocar flechas de continuidad a un carrousel jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día, como podría poner flechas de continuidad a este plugin "[Menu Slide](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Simple-Slide-Out-Drawer-Effect-Plugin/)" ya que voy a colocar 15 elementos en la lista y quisiera que se muestren los que sean posibles dentro del ancho determinado de una pantalla.

GRACIAS

Comment: Hola amigo, lo que solicitas es muy general. Y aparte solo muestras el plugin, alterarlo y editarlo toma mucho tiempo así que no tiene una respuesta corta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas Joel Sulca Cordova ,
Tras ver funcionando el plugin y darle un par de vueltas veo una solución fácil y rápida. Seguramente se pueda hacer de otra forma y empaquetando la dentro del mismo plugin.

Bueno ahí va:

1º añadimos un poco de css al contenedor del elemento ul, al ul y a los li.

```
.drawer-items{width: auto !important;}
.drawer-items ul {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
.drawer-items li {
   float: none !important;
   list-style: none;
   margin-left: 0px;
   width: 200px;
   display: table-cell !important;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2º Lo que haremos será mover el primer elemento al último (Cuando hagamos clic en la flecha de la derecha)  y que el último se ponga el primero (Cuando le hagamos click a la flecha de la izquierda). Para ello tendremos estas líneas de javascript :

```
 function MoverLista(derecha){
    var ul = $('.drawer-items>ul');
    //para la derecha
    if(derecha) 
        ul.children('li:first-child').appendTo(ul);
    else 
      ul.children('li:last-child').prependTo(ul);
    //para la izquierda
 }
```

3º Ahora necesitamos introducir dos elementos html que funcionen como las flechas y que al hacerle clic ejecuten esta función. Por ejemplo haciendo algo como esto:

```
<div class="drawer-content">
        <div class="drawer-navigation">
            <a class="drawer-left" href="javascript:MoverLista(false)">Izquierda</a>
            <a class="drawer-right"href="javascript:MoverLista(true)">Derecha</a>
        </div>
        <div class="drawer-items"> 
            <ul>...
```

5º Si ademas añadimos algo de css a nuestro .drawer-navigation, como aquí:

```
.drawer-navigation{ 
    width: 100%;  
    position: relative;
}
.drawer-navigation a{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    height: 140px;
    width:100px;
    display: block; 
    color:orange;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
} 
.drawer-navigation a:hover{
    background: orange;
    color:black;
}
.drawer-navigation a.drawer-left{
    left:0px;
}
.drawer-navigation a.drawer-right{
    right:0px !important;
}
```

Veremos algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos definir un icono , imagen ... para las flechas , pero en cuestión ya tendremos funcionando el slider de elementos. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS, FUNCIONA!

Comment: Me alegra poder haberte ayudado.